# One single class for const and non-const iterators. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm implementing a custom container with an STL-like interface for a 3D grid control for my scientific software. This is my second question regarding the iterator class for this container. Thanks for helping me with [the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050429/stl-iterator-dereferencing-iterator-to-a-temporary-is-it-possible)!

My question is just like ["How do you avoid code duplication when implementing const and non-const iterators?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150192/how-do-you-avoid-code-duplication-when-implementing-const-and-non-const-iterators). I just wanted to ask if it is possible to provide a **template-less solution**? (And without providing a second const iterator class!)

The iterator class looks like this:

```
class spGridIterator {
public:
    typedef forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef spGridNode value_type;
    typedef int difference_type;
    typedef spGridNode* pointer;
    typedef spGridNode& reference;

    spGridIterator();
    spGridIterator(spGrid* gr, int index);
    spGridIterator(const spGridIterator& orig);
    virtual ~spGridIterator();

    // STL-ные операторы итератора
    bool operator == ( const spGridIterator& hs ) const {
        return (m_grid == hs.m_grid) && (m_idx == hs.m_idx);
    }

    bool operator != ( const spGridIterator& hs ) const {
        return (m_grid != hs.m_grid) || (m_idx != hs.m_idx);
    }

    // non-const operators
    spGridIterator& operator++();
    spGridIterator& operator++(int);

    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const { return &(operator*()); }

private:
    spGrid* m_grid;
    int m_idx;
};
```

And an implementation...

```
spGridIterator::spGridIterator(spGrid* gr, int index) {
    m_grid = gr;
    m_idx  = index;
}

spGridIterator& spGridIterator::operator++()
{
    int last = m_grid->numpoints;

    if (m_idx < last) {
        m_idx++;
    }
    return *this;
}

spGridIterator& spGridIterator::operator++(int) {
    return operator++();
}

spGridIterator::reference spGridIterator::operator*() const {
    return ( m_grid->GetNode(m_idx) );
}
```

I checked the [doctor dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401331) about custom iterator implementation. They suggest implementing an iterator class template and adding an additional template parameter for the `value_type`.

Well, the second solution is to provide a regular iterator and a const iterator classes.

Is there third, maybe "kinda hacky", single class template-less solution? Maybe providing a conversion operator or an additional const version of `operator++()`?

Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: Your `operator++(int)` returns the wrong value - it's postfix `++`, so it should return a copy of the iterator *prior* to being incremented, not a reference to the iterator *after* being iterated. Canonical implementation is `Iterator Iterator::operator++(int) { Iterator old = *this; ++(*this); return old; }`

Comment: I've got it! Thanks for a valuable comment!

Comment: I not really needed I would not implement the postfix ++ operator.  You really want to encourage people using the prefix ++ operator instead of the postfix ++ operator.

Comment: @Patrick: good idea, but if it doesn't have postfix ++ then it isn't an iterator, according to the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go kind of hacky, you may be able to abuse "const_cast" to create a const iterator out of a non-const one.

Comment: Simple trick, but it works.  Don't forget to clearly comment in the source code why you are abusing the const_cast.  Otherwise, the next developer reading the code will think that you made a mistake and will want to correct your error, euh trick.